# R: Pushing column into data.frame function

Tags: r, shiny, data-analysis

This is probably going to be a really dumb question but here we go.

Dummy dataset:

```
  id  x  y   t 
  1  10 20   8   
  1  11 14  40    
  2  19 16  18
  2  14 54  15     
  2  10 27  29       
  2  15 21  5
  3  40 18  19      
  3  23 13  30
```

Using Shiny I want to plot x and y when their time(t) comes along in a slider that I have already built in the UI. Using the data.frame function I want to store all these values into df. I know I can manually do it doing something like this below.

server.R

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("1","1","2"), 
             x=c(10,11,19), 
             y=c(20,14,16),
             t=c(8,40,18))
```

So my question is, how can I store all these values into df without having to hard code it all in? Over 100k obs...

Comment: This question must be a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the vectors, you just add them to the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id, x, y, t)
```

If you can only copy and paste the data, you can use read.table:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  id  x  y   t 
  1  10 20   8   
  1  11 14  40    
  2  19 16  18
  2  14 54  15     
  2  10 27  29       
  2  15 21  5
  3  40 18  19      
  3  23 13  30", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read it from a file using `read.table` as shown below.

```
bash$ cat t00T.txt
id  x  y   t
1  10 20   8
1  11 14  40
2  19 16  18
2  14 54  15
2  10 27  29
2  15 21  5
3  40 18  19
3  23 13  30
bash$ R -q
> read.table("t00T.txt", header=TRUE)
  id  x  y  t
1  1 10 20  8
2  1 11 14 40
3  2 19 16 18
4  2 14 54 15
5  2 10 27 29
6  2 15 21  5
7  3 40 18 19
8  3 23 13 30
>
```